# Why isn't my Angular App displaying my html?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I entered the following code into app.component.html, however when viewing the angular app in the browser, nothing loads.
I have removed all `<html><body>` and `<head>` tags. As I believed this was the problem.

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="maincont">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        {{title}}
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/login">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="heading">
      <center>{{title}}</center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projects" id="projects">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="cell">
        <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt fugiat ab ducimus culpa ratione iure
          fugit, placeat dolor eveniet dignissimos!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <h1>Lorem, ipsum.</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto repudiandae quia dolorum, esse,
          perferendis odio, temporibus debitis inventore vitae officia animi. Quas temporibus voluptate consequatur
          mollitia dolorem optio vel libero!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti molestiae deserunt voluptates tenetur
          ducimus dolore similique, ratione sit blanditiis! Quaerat illo earum autem hic?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <h1>Lorem.</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veritatis nisi assumenda itaque inventore neque
          exercitationem. Voluptatem libero ducimus eos aliquam porro odio modi facilis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The other files (app.component.ts, app.component.css) are unchanged after running;

```
ng new App
```

Comment: https://angular.io/cli follow this guide and paste your html into the app.component.html There is just something wrong with your setup, we can't help with only your HTML because it seems okay

Comment: Ctrl+F5 - make sure nothing is cached in your browser!

Answer (score 0):

The `<center>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead. The `<center>` tag is used to center-align text.
so use css instead of using center tag

Comment: You can check this on www.caniuse.com

Answer (score 0):

I tried your Html and yea, looks like the `<center>` tag is not supported.  `<div style="text-align:center"></div>` should fix it!

I came to this conclusion by using Developer Tools (F12) while running your code and looking at the "Console" for guidance